# Why reducing rep for downvoting item one had previously upvoted?

Tags: bug, down-votes, reputation, up-votes

I upvoted an answer to a question, and after a few seconds realized I had upvoted the wrong answer, so I hit the downvote button to put it back the way it was.  After moving on to another question I noticed I had lost a rep point.

Why would changing an upvote be regarded as a downvote?  This amounts to a returning of the status quo ante, and since the system clearly knows it was me who upvoted it, it should surely be able to tell that it is I who downvotes, and thus treat it as a neutral act, not an actual downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, if you hit the downvote from a positive vote (+1), it does not return to the previous state (0), but the answer loses a vote (-1).

If you want to cancel your vote, click on the same arrow you used in the first place.

I think this is not a bug, but something the users should know.

Comment: Ah ha.  Don't know why I missed this.  I have been participating in Stack Exchanges for a couple of years now.  I guess I've never tried to reverse my vote before.

Comment: I can't understand why someone *downvoted* this. So far as I know, it's absolutely correct, and it seems well-expressed to me.